# Do black hats make the Jew?

Tags: halacha, kippa-yarmulka, black-hats

It seems that wearing a hat is required, because the Shulchan Aruch says you need to wear a double covering.  But some apparently-frum men don't wear a hat.  How is this possible?

Comment: This question is clearly abusive. Plus, this is already addressed on this site. I recommend deletion

Comment: Hello and welcome to Mi Yodeya.  You could improve this question by citing where in SA it says that, and what exactly it means by "double covering".  A hat (of any color) might not be the only way to achieve that goal.

Comment: See: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/781/why-wear-black-hats

Comment: Sourcing your claim about Shulchan Aruch's position would greatly increase your question's value. Also, why do you think a double covering means a hat? Maybe it means two layers of tin foil.

Comment: -1 Please cite a source for this supposed statement by the Shulchan Aruch. See also the comments on [this question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/28281).

Comment: @ThehatmakestheJew, do you want to fix this question to have it reopened, or would you prefer the mods delete it (as you [have indicated](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/revisions/29158/1) that this question was meant as a joke)?

Answer (score 2):

Many Yarmulkas are made from a top and bottom part which = 2 coverings. True Torah Judaism has absolutely nothing to do with the hat you wear.

Comment: Source that two layers of material in a yarmulka are better than one? This claim is ubiquitous, but I've never seen anyone able to produce a source.

Comment: I Believe Rav Eliyashiv also held there is no source ,brought in sefer Vayishma Moshe ,will locate it later.

Comment: even though they're sowed together?

Answer (score 2):

No. The SA isn't the end all be all. The Biur HaGR"A (O.H. 8:6) even suggests that one can say berakhoth without a head covering. The idea that one cannot be an authentic representative of "true Torah Judaism" without a particular style of head-covering is absurd. This [article](http://www.hakirah.org/Vol%204%20Rabinowitz.pdf) is chock full of information on the topic of head-coverings.

Comment: @ThehatmakestheJew, glad to be of assistance :)