# How we can we mutar shaving?

Tags: halacha, shaving

It says in sefer vayikra in perek יט posuk כז, "You shall not round off the corner of your head, and you shall not destroy the edge of your beard." Now I shave my face because many poskim have made shaving mutar, but how can they do that? This posuk seems to be pretty explicit. I know you can interpret it differently,but wouldn't it be better that we be machmir just in case we are misinterpreting the posuk?

Comment: Did your poskim permit you to destroy your beard or to cut it really short?

Comment: But isn't cutting it short a form of destruction? Cutting half a building to make it smaller is also destruction

Comment: I didn't realize your English translation and the subtleties of the English language were so relevant here.

Comment: @ThehatmakestheJew - we are not dealing with the general conceptual idea of destruction and everything that the word can broadly communicate - we are dealing with the legal definition of the word "השחתה" in context as communicated in Hazalic sources.

Comment: related http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0321.htm#5

Comment: Same question here [as over here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29075/do-black-hats-make-the-jew#comment71939_29075). Do you want to fix this question?

Answer (score 13):

As the Rambam states in H. A"Z 12:8:

**ואינו חייב עד שיגלחנו בתער--שנאמר "ולא תשחית, את פאת זקנך" (ויקרא יט,כז), גילוח שיש בו השחתה; לפיכך אם גילח זקנו במספריים, פטור.  ואין המתגלח לוקה, עד שיסייע.**

*One is liable only when one shaves with a razor, as [implied by Leviticus 19:27]: "Do not destroy the corners of your beard." [We can infer that this applies only] to shaving which utterly destroys [one's facial hair]. Therefore, a person who removes his beard with scissors is exempt.*

Some debate whether it is patur aval assur or that that there is a free license altogether (Sefer ha-Hinukh vs Beth Yosef).