# Black Hats During Mussaf

Tags: tefilla, minhag, synagogue, black-hats

Lately, I have noticed that many people who wear a tallis during davening will deliberately put on the black hat, which they wore on the way to shul, while still wearing their tallis near the end of the chazzan's recitation of mussaf. I have observed people going well out of their way to the coatroom just to get their hat for this when they easily could have gotten their hat as they were leaving shul.

Is there any explanation for this practice? Wouldn't it make more sense for them to put on their hats after taking off their tallis?

Comment: Re "...after taking off their tallis": or after _t'fila_, for those who continue to wear the _talis_ after _t'fila_.

Comment: Tzvi, the custom is not just with black hats; it is also with Streimelech. Also, you observed those who do not know the custom, whatever its origins are. The custom is to put it on after the completion of the beracha of kedushah (HaKeil HaKadosh) except when there is Bircas Kohanim because the Tallis is placed over the head for BK.

Comment: Since when did the black hat become *tashmish kedusha*, such that it matter when you put it on or not put it on?

Comment: @AviD, when did the _kipa_, or for that matter, the _talis_? Hats are certainly mentioned in _halacha_. (No citation at the moment.)

Comment: @msh210 really? I would be very shocked if it was mentioned as a halachic item (besides just covering one's head), as opposed to an item that everyone is expected to have (such as shoes). Along the lines of, "How could he go outside without his hat?". If you can find such a source, I would be so shocked I would eat my hat ;)

Comment: @AviD, I thought a hat was mentioned in _Baer Hetev_ or _Shaare S'shuva_ in _hilchos bhm"z_, but don't see it there now. I don't know what an "halachic item" is. Note that a _kipa_ doesn't need to be a _tashmish k'dusha_ or _tashmish mitzva_ to be required to wear it. (Well, more accurately, to be required to wear _something_, but that same consideration — having to wear _something_ — can apply to the practice in question here.)

Comment: @msh210 I agree, the *something* could be a kipa, a black hat, a white skullcap or a yellow turban for that matter. My point was, assuming one is already wearing a kipa, there is not a halachic imperative to put on an additional covering at any particular point in the prayers, and surely not specifically a "black hat".

Comment: @AviD, re "assuming one is already wearing a kipa, there is not a halachic imperative to put on an additional covering at any particular point in the prayers", that's where I think you're wrong, though, again, I have no citation now.

Comment: @AviD @msh210 : see the article linked to in this answer: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/781/why-wear-black-hats/783#783  . He brings and analyzes 5 reasons why people wear black hats during prayer.

Comment: @Menachem, thank you, I will definitely be looking at that (it *is* long...). However note also the sensible 2nd answer, given in that same question by @Shalom, which lines up with what I said: as far as most books written more than a few years ago, *of course* one would wear a hat, you always do. But not really, anymore.

Comment: @msh210 Regarding hats being an halachic item, I think that you are recalling the idea of considering a hat atifa.  Regarding your question, I am surprised that there is a basis to it.  I always thought that people got antsy toward the end of davening.  Just as some would start putting away their talis, others properly keep it on, but put on there hats as they prepare to finish.

Comment: @YDK, it's not my question. And according to Yahu's comment ("The custom is to put it on after the completion of the beracha of kedushah (HaKeil HaKadosh)..."), there must be something more to it.

Comment: @msh210: I did find another blog where one of the commenters mentions that it is a custom to put on a black hat after mussaf kedusha on shabbos. http://chaverai.blogspot.com/2007/01/fear-of-black-hat.html

Comment: There is a rule somwehere, that you should double cover your head for shemonah esrei, and that you should not remove that double covering. It's implied that the double covering is your talit and some other head covering.

Answer (score 6):

In [Tzitzit Halacha LeMa'aseh](http://store.kehotonline.com/index.php?stocknumber=HL-TZIT&deptid=3269&parentid=83&page=5&itemsperpage=10) (Chapter 9, footnote 12), The Leket HaKemach HaChadash (8:16) Is quoted as saying:

> The custom in Germany is that the whole congregation  only covers their head (with the Tallit) while saying Shema on Yom Kippur and Yom Kippur Katan. However, many of the G-d fearing put a hat on top of their Kippah if they are not covering their heads (with the Tallit).

I wasn't able to find a copy of the sefer to read it inside, so I'm not entirely sure the context, but that would seem to be a source for putting on a hat when the Tallit is taken off the head.

[This appears to be the Sefer, by R' Yaakov Tzi Katz](http://www.otzar.org/wotzar/Book.aspx?84205&&lang=eng&lang=eng), but the relevant section is not part of the free preview.

---

The question then becomes, why remove the Tallit from one's head at the end of Mussaf.

There is a Sicha from the Previous Lubavitcher Rebbe from the second night of Chol HaMo'ed Sukkot 5697 (1936), where he mentions that there is a Kabbalistic reason to remove the Tallit from one's head by the Ein Ke'lokeinu prayer (which immediately follows the Chazan's repetition of the Mussaf Amidah). [Chapter 12 footnote 65 of Tzitzit Halacha LeMa'aseh points out that this does not appear to be the Chabad custom]

---

So to put these two ideas together. If one deliberately removes the Tallit from his head by Ein Ke'lokeinu, but wants to have another covering on his head when the Tallit is removed from his head, he will have to go get his his hat before the chazzan concludes the repetition of the Mussaf Amidah.

I have no idea if this is what the members of the synagogue in your question have in mind.

Comment: There was a time when German Jews commonly wore top hats at services.

Comment: @BruceJames, not so long ago. When my grandfather was young, all of the adult men wore them in schul. Actually, it was kind of like a shtreimel in that regard.

Answer (score 5):

It  seems that Shulchan Oruch Orach Chayim 124 (4) describes the correct conduct during the chazzan's repetition of the Amidah, "they should be quiet and concentrate on the brochos said by the chazzan and answer omain ....." No mention is made there of changing head covering, still less of "going well out of their way to the coatroom just to get their hat".