# What is "going" in terms of head covering?

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara, words, head-covering

related: [Kippa in Torah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/751/kippa-in-torah)

The talmud in Kiddush 31a [relates](https://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.31a.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) that

> רב הונא בריה דרב יהושע לא מסגי ארבע אמות בגילוי הראש
> "Rav Huna, son of Rav Yehoshua, would not walk four cubits with an uncovered head".

The talmud uses the word [misgei](https://www.morfix.co.il/%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%92%D7%99) which is presented (switching from, I'm guessing, the Aramaic) by the Rif as שיהלך (and understood as that by the [Steinzaltz](https://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.31a.3?lang=bi&with=Steinsaltz&lang2=en)). The [Aramaic](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/A_Dictionary_of_the_Targumim,_the_Talmud_Babli_and_Yerushalmi,_and_the_Midrashic_Literature/%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%92%D7%99_-_%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A7%D7%AA%D7%90) itself, as evidenced by its use in the targum, seems to refer to an abundance or something not about "going."

> ‎מסגי ‎m. ‎(סגי ‎I) ‎multitude. ‎Targ. ‎Y. ‎Deut. ‎X, ‎22. ‎Targ. ‎O. ‎Gen. ‎XXX, ‎80; ‎a. ‎e. ‎--Targ. ‎Is. ‎V, ‎24, ‎v. ‎מסגן.]-V. ‎סגיIII.

I'm not sure what exact word is being used (if it isn't the Aramaic) or how the word is actually used in this context -- it seems weird that a statement in Hebrew would be punctuated by an Aramaic word, especially when there are Hebrew ones readily available. But because I don't fully understand that word, I don't understand its scope and limitations.

Would this rabbi only apply this head covering to "going" which is walking? Would riding on a horse be the same "going"? I know that some people, using a more modern Hebrew, distinguish between h-l-ch (go, implying walking) and n-s-a (travel, implying another form of movement).

Would someone sitting on a boat or an airplane, who is certainly traveling but not walking, still be "required" (acknowledging the notion that this is a custom, so I'm hesitant to use the absolute language of "obligated") to have his head covered?

Are there responsa which deal with this and clarify what "misgei" applies to?

Comment: Did you see the second entry in Jastrow for סגי/סגא? [here](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/A_Dictionary_of_the_Targumim,_the_Talmud_Babli_and_Yerushalmi,_and_the_Midrashic_Literature/%D7%A1%D7%92%D7%99_-_%D7%A1%D7%92%D7%99%D7%A8)

Comment: I saw this https://www.sefaria.org/Jastrow%2C_%D7%A1%D6%B0%D7%92%D6%B5%D7%99_III.1?lang=bi -- it connects the word used to definition 3, not 2.

Comment: [This Jastrow entry](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Jastrow%2C_%D7%A1%D6%B0%D7%92%D6%B5%D7%99_%C2%B2?lang=bi) quotes an almost identical passage from Shabbat 118b. This is the etymology you're looking for

Comment: If so, is it an Aramaic word or a Hebrew one (as one level of my question is about the use of Aramaic in a statement in Hebrew? Regardless, it would still leave the underying question unresolved.

Comment: The word is Aramaic, although as Jastrow points out it is related to the biblical שגי/שגה meaning to grow, and by extension to spread out

Comment: I saw recently that Rav Elyashiv says a child should start wearing a head covering from the time they start walking, i.e. crawling is not considered "going". (However, it seems to me the more common custom is to wait until a child is 3 years old.)

Comment: Acc to the taz in Siman 2 last sif he would see there